# How to deploy .exe to scheduler task using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, command-line

I developed a console app and scheduled it to run on Mon-Friday at 9:AM using windows task scheduler, it works fine.

But I was asked to write Powershell scripts or command-line scripts for deployment, like the script should copy the "Release" folder to the server1(deployment env like dev, test or staging or prod) and schedule it in server1's schedule task. Also I have to set "Start in(optional)".

I don't know anything about command-line and PS scripts. All it should do is create the windows schedule task just like the way I did using UI.

Comment: What have you tried in order to accomplish this task? Why are you being tasked with automating scheduled task deployment if you have no knowledge on the subject? Tell us what research you've already done and what you've tried.

Comment: Now I can't answer you such questions, it is just me being ready to take it up and show my flexibility towards work, if needed learn new things, and work. I am looking into some cmds like $tigger etc but cannot make it happen, also looking at "Schtasks.exe", Any good examples are appreciated

Comment: I can understand being flexible and ready to learn new things, but you should do some research on your own. Stack Overflow is a place to come for a specific problem you're having while trying to accomplish your task, not a place for you to come ask others to do your work for you. Research creating scheduled tasks with powershell first and give it a go. The link Samsonaod posted is a good starting point.

Comment: No problem if you have not understood or don't no solution, I already completed it. I have some security issues
Otherwise this will work :
schtasks /Create 
[/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
[/RU username [/RP [password]] /SC schedule [/MO modifier] [/D day]
[/M months] [/I idletime] /TN taskname /TR taskrun [/ST starttime]
[/RI interval] [ {/ET endtime | /DU duration} [/K] 
[/XML xmlfile] [/V1]] [/SD startdate] [/ED enddate] [/IT] [/Z] [/F]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/schtasks

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, you should post the answer below for others to read if they are trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes Dusty, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a requirement to schedule an exe, this scheduled task should run every day Mon to Fri at desired time. I never wrote any batch files in last 15 years of my career :), took it up as it came in my way from my manager. Thanks to him or else I would have not known in this new world.

echo off
title My 1st batch file for Task scheduler
SchTasks /Create /RU "system" /Sc WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /TN "Leads" /TR "C:/Some.exe" /ST 09:00

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you're just trying to create a scheduled task using powershell?
If so try starting here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/13/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/